# Find the images of half plane X>0 and y<1 under the linear fractional transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

[image]

My attempt on this question
[image]
Please help how to proceed further

Answer (score 2):

You might as well check where the boundary lines $x=0$ and $y=1$ go.  They will go to either circles or lines...

So, for the half plane  $x\ge0$, let's use $0,i$ and $\infty  $.  So $T (0)=\frac  {0+i}{0-i}=-1, T (i)=\frac  {i+i}{i-i}=\infty  $ and  $T (\infty )=1$.  So, evidently the line  $x=0$ gets sent to the line through  $1,-1$ and $\infty  $, that is,  the x-axis .  Use a test point, say $1+i$, to see if the half plane goes above or below . ..  $T (1+i)=\frac  {1+i+i}{1+i-i} =1+2i$, which is above the x-axis . ..

Do the same sort of thing with  $y\le1$...
So, let's use  $i, 1+i$ and  $\infty  $...  $T (i)=\infty,  T (1+i)=1+2i $ and $T (\infty )=1$.  Evidently we have a vertical line (the points are colinear)...
Now to check which side use a test point.   How about  $0$?  We already did it...  $T (0)=-1$.  So to the left of the line...